# Xamarin missing generated classes from JAR

Tags: android, xamarin, mapbox

I am trying to create Xamarin android bindings for MapBox but it seems like a couple of the classes are not being generated:

**WeakReferenceRunnable**

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk/blob/mb-pages/MapboxAndroidSDK/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/bitmapcache/WeakReferenceRunnable.java

**BitmapLruCache**

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk/blob/mb-pages/MapboxAndroidSDK/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/bitmapcache/BitmapLruCache.java

I have looked through the suggestions on http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar) but no luck with any of theses.

Is there anything else which could be causing this?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? Looking for similar answers myself.